# Modular polynomial problem

Tags: polynomials

Let $f(x) := 2x^3 + ax^2 + bx + 6$. When $f(x)$ is divided by $x − 3$, the remainder is $0$, and when $f(x)$ is divided by $x − 1$, the remainder is $6$.

How to determine the values of the constants a and b?

Comment: 3 is a root of the given polynomial that will give you the first equation of two unknowns a and b! moreover you have that P(x)=Q(x)(x-1)+6! substituting x=1 will give you the second equation containing a and b! 2 equations 2 unknowns, its done! goodluck

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

If the remainder of a polynomial $f(x)$ divided by $x-3$ is $0$ then that means that $3$ is a root of that polynomial. Hence $$f(3)=0\iff 2(3)^3+a(3)^2+b(3)+6=0.$$
You obtain an equation with two unknowns. Now can you make another reasoning (based on that $f(x)$ divided by $x-1$ leaves a reminder of $6$) to find another equation with the two unknowns $a,b$?

Answer (score 0):

The remainder of the division by a degree $1$ polynomial $X-a$ is a constant so we have $$f(X)=(X-a)Q(X)+c$$ substituting $X$ by $a$ we get $f(a)=c$. This means in our case that $f(3)=0$ and $f(1)=6$ This yields the following system $$\begin{cases} 9a+3b+60=0\\a+b+8=6 \end{cases}$$